# swift: collectionView animation

Tags: ios, swift

Я использую этот код для создания анимации кнопки:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        switch indexPath.section { 
        case 0:
            self.button1.constant = 50
        case 6:
            self.button3.constant = 50
        default:
            self.button1.constant = 0
            self.button3.constant = 0
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                       options: [], animations: {
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
}
```

У меня есть `collectionView`. Но вместе с анимацией кнопок мой `collectionView` тоже выполняет анимацию. Как это исправить? Мне нужна анимация только кнопок.

Comment: попробуйте UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                       options: [], animations: {
                        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

Comment: @ВикторМишустин У collectionView анимация осталась. У кнопок нет.

Comment: Сложно будет дать ответ. Непонятно, каково взаиморасположение кнопок и collectionView.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Для кнопок у меня есть ограничения safe area и superview. Также ограничение по высоте и ширине. Для collectionView у меня есть ограничения safe area и superview

Comment: @user А какая анимация у collectionView включается?

Comment: @RomanPodymov увеличение от маленького размер до текущего размера.

Comment: @RomanPodymov использую это `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {` Чтобы определить размер

Comment: @user А у каждой кнопки отдельно layoutIfNeeded() вызывать не пробовали? Просто у Вас в приведённом фрагменте кода нет ссылок на кнопки, только на ограничения в их размере (насколько я понял).

Comment: @RomanPodymov пробовал. Не работает анимация. Я не понимаю почему для кнопок она не работает. `@IBOutlet weak var mButton: UIButton!` `mButton.layoutIfNeeded()` так вызываю.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Мне нужно добавить больше кода? Или еще что? Напишите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @RomanPodymov Все работает нормально если вместо `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` поставлю `self.view.layoutSubviews()`. Это хорошее решение или нет?

Comment: @user У Вас не хватает очков репутации, чтобы продолжить обсуждение в чате?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Да. Я не сразу понял, что Вы в чате пишете. У меня почему-то не сразу появилось предложение.

Comment: @user И всё-таки, Вы в блоке вызвать { self.view.setNeedsLayout(); self.view.layoutIfNeeded() } пробовали?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Пробовал. Анимация у `collectionView` работает.

Comment: @user А можете показать код с анимацией collectionView?

Comment: @RomanPodymov У меня нет кода для анимации `collectionView`. Есть код в вопросе. Он для анимации кнопок. Но вместе с ним анимация появляется у `collectionView` хотя мне она не нужна. В этом и проблема.

Comment: @user То есть у Вас sizeForItemAt вызывается после этого? А там Вы в зависимости от какого-то условия меняете размер ячеек?